# How to use the resampling function to create 23 hour average data

Tags: python, dataframe, mean, pandas-resample

I want to make an average every 23 hours from 10:00 a.m to 9:00 a.m. the next day.
but i can't find solution

```
newDf = Data_s.resample(rule='H').mean()
```

I think I can change this code, but I don't know how.
My data are divided from March 11th to April 10th, 23.
like that
2022-03-11 00:00
2022-03-11 00:01
....
2022-04-11 00:00

I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there is a way

thank you

i try like that

```
newDf = Data_s.resample(rule='23H',origin=).mean()
```

but It only makes an average for 23 hours in a row.
and other simple method is delete data (just 8 a.m) but i want to know how can make it by code
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since "every 23 hours from 10:00 a.m to 9:00 a.m" means exluding the '9th hour', here's one possible way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time": pd.date_range(start="2022-03-11 00:00", end="2022-04-11 00:00", freq="min"),
    "value": 1
})

hour_to_exclude = 9
time_subset = df[df["time"].dt.hour != hour_to_exclude]
time_subset.resample("D", on="time").mean()
```

Output:

```
            value
      time  
2022-03-11  1.0
2022-03-12  1.0
2022-03-13  1.0
2022-03-14  1.0
2022-03-15  1.0
...
```